# Синий экран смерти после командной строки Windows

Tags: windows

Сначала командная строка с этой надписью:

> DISPLAY: 'oYIoIQAFC' TYPE: DOWNLOAD STATE: TRANSFERRING PRIORITY: HIGH FILES: 0 / 1 BYTES: 91589 / 388652 (23%) TRANSFER RATE: 32,43 KB/S TIME REMAINING: 9 Seconds

Потом появляется синий экран смерти `ошибка 0x00000f4`.
Установлена Windows 7 64-разрядная система.

Comment: Если ничего не удалось нагуглить и здесь Вам не ответят, задайте вопрос на OSZone. Шансы на успех повысятся, если будете следовать [**данным инструкциям**](http://forum.oszone.net/thread-275050.html). Спасибо.

Comment: Повторяется? С помощью blue screen view (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)  смотрели?

Comment: Подозреваю наличие троя.